# When is the dimension of the fixed point set of an isometry defined?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

## The very short version

For any isometry $\sigma$,
the fixed point set $\text{Fix}(\sigma)$ is a union of submanifolds.
When is the dimension well-defined?

## The long version

In the following, let $M$ always be a Riemannian manifold.
The quotes were slightly changed for consistency.

### What I found in the literature

In Klingenberg [1] we can read

> **1.10.15 Theorem.** Let $\sigma\colon M \to M$ be an isometry.
>   Then every connected component of the fixed point set
>   $\text{Fix}(\sigma) := \{p \in M : \sigma(p) = p\}$
>   is a totally geodesic submanifold.

and Kobayashi [2] writes

> **Theorem 5.1.** Let $\mathfrak S$ be any set of isometries of $M$.
>   Let $\text{Fix}(\mathfrak S)$ be the set of points of $M$
>   which are left fixed by all elements of $\mathfrak S$.
>   Then each connected component of $\text{Fix}(\mathfrak S)$
>   is a closed totally geodesic submanifold of $M$.

The latter is at least as strong as the first one, of course.
The only concrete example given is in Klingenberg
and [appears](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011835/frustrating-experience-about-differential-geometry#comment2066082_1011835) to be just a reflection of the $n$-sphere,
where we easily see the components to be of identical dimension.
Neither explicitly mentions
the possibility of the components having different dimensions.

However, Donnelly and Patodi [3][4] write (emphasis mine)

> Let $M$ be a *compact* Riemannian manifold of dimension $d$
>   and $\sigma\colon M \to M$ an isometry […].
>   $\text{Fix}(\sigma)$ is the disjoint union
>   of closed connected submanifolds $N$ of dimension $n$.

This gave me hope
that in the compact case all the connected components had the same dimension,
but later on [5] they write

> Let $\sigma$ be an isometry of the compact Riemannian manifold $M$.
>   The fixed point set of $\sigma$ is the disjoint union
>   of compact connected totally geodesic submanifolds $N$.

and as far as I can tell,
they only use $n$ as soon as an $N$ is fixed,
so I'm assuming I overinterpreted an implicit dependency of $n$ on $N$.

### What I would like to know

My question is easily phrased as three:

- What are examples where the components of such fixed point sets
  have different dimensions?
- What conditions can be required
  of $\mathfrak S \subseteq \text{Aut}(M)$ / $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(M)$
  such that $\text{Fix}(\mathfrak S)$ / $\text{Fix}(\sigma)$
  is of uniform dimension?
- What conditions can be placed on $M$
  such that $\text{Fix}(\mathfrak S)$ / $\text{Fix}(\sigma)$
  has a well-defined dimension for all such $\mathfrak S$ / $\sigma$?

In the end,
I would like to have as much of a sharp separation between the cases
as is possible.
The questions above all tackle this same problem from different directions.

### What is trivial

The following repeatedly led to confusion,
so I'm saying these right now:

- Yes, if $M$ is not connected,
  counterexamples are trivial to come by.
  I'm only interested in the case where $M$ is connected.
- Yes, if $\text{Fix}(\mathfrak S)$ is connected, too,
  the dimension is well-defined by the standard argument.
- No, the fixed points are not always connected.
  Think about a reflection of the 1-sphere
  or a rotation of the 2-sphere.

### What we found out

I'm probably forgetting something
but here is what else we know:

- All the standard examples we know and most stuff we came up with
  was highly symmetrical.
  This might explain why we failed to find counterexamples.
- Isometries fix geodesics between fixed points
  as long as the geodesics are unique
  for their length.
  This shows for example
  that on the sphere
  the only way to obtain a disconnected fixed point set
  is for it to consist of two antipodal points only.

## Links

[1]: Wilhelm Klingenberg, Riemannian Geometry.
Page 95 at [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=e1RoufV3eiIC).

[2]: Shoshichi Kobayashi, Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry.
Referenced at [Fixed Points Set of an Isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55376/fixed-points-set-of-an-isometry).

[3]: Harold Donnelly,
[Spectrum and fixed point sets of isometries. I](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01436198.pdf).
Directly in the beginning.

[4]: Harold Donnelly and V. K. Patodi,
[Spectrum and fixed point sets of isometries—II](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938377900271).
Directly in the beginning.

[5]:
Same as [4]. At the start of §2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an example of variable dimension of the fixed-point set, take $M=RP^2$ (with a constant curvature metric) and $\sigma$ an isometric reflection. (The projection of a reflection on $S^2$.) Then $Fix(\sigma)$ is a disjoint union of a point and a projective line. You can get more examples like this in higher dimensions. I am not sure about the rest of your questions.

Edit: If $\sigma$ is an isometry of a 2-dimensional **orientable** connected Riemannian manifold then $Fix(\sigma)$ has constant dimension. The reason is that near an isolated fixed point, $\sigma$ would preserve orientation and near a non-isolated fixed point $\sigma$ would have to reverse orientation.  But a homeomorphism of a connected oriented manifold cannot both preserve and reverse orientation.

By working a bit more one can show the following: For every $n$ there exists an $n$-dimensional connected compact Riemannian manifold $M$ and an isometry $\sigma: M\to M$ whose fixed point set contains components of all possible dimensions: $0, 1, 2,..., n-1$.

Here is a construction. First of all, let $M_0,...,M_{n-1}$ be compact connected $n$-dimensional manifolds equipped with involutions $\sigma_0,...,\sigma_{n-1}$ such that $dim(Fix(\sigma_i))=i$. Furthermore, for each $i$ pick points $x_i, y_i\in M_i- Fix(\sigma_i)$ and set $x_i':= \sigma_i(x_i), y_i':= \sigma_i(y_i)$. I am assuming that these choices are generic so that for each $i$ all four points $x_i, x_i', y_i, y_i'$ are distinct. Now, form a connected manifold $M$ by performing a generalized connected sum along small disjoint balls $B_i, B_i', C_i, C_i'$ centered at the points $x_i, x_i', y_i, y_i'$, $i=0,...,n-1$, so that $\sigma_i(B_i)=C_i, \sigma(B_i')=C_i'$.

Namely, remove all these balls from the disjoint union 
$$
\coprod_i M_i
$$
("puncturing each $M_i$") and perform gluing via diffeomorphisms
$$
f_i: \partial C_i\to \partial B_{i+1}, \partial f_i': C_i'\to \partial B_{i+1}', 
$$
$i=0, 1,....$. Choose these diffeomorphisms so that
$$
\sigma_{i+1}\circ f_i= f_i'\circ \sigma_i, i=0, 1,.... 
$$
The result of this gluing is a smooth connected manifold $M$ equipped with a diffeomorphic involution $\sigma$ (whose restriction to each punctured $M_i$ equals $\sigma_i$). Lastly, put a $\sigma$-invariant Riemannian metric on $M$.

Comment: If one wants M to be simply connected, consider the $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{C}P^n$ given in homogeneous coordinates by $z\ast[z_0:...:z_n] = [zz_0: z_1:...:z_n]$.  This fixes the point $[1:0:...:0]$ as well as the $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ given by $[0:z_1:...:z_n]$.  By having the circle hit more coordinates, you can arrange the fixed point sets to be any pair $\mathbb{C}P^a, \mathbb{C}P^b$ with $a+b = n-1$.

Comment: Can you give some idea what “By workig a bit more” entails? I see how to get arbitrary combinations by yours or Jason DeVitos example, but my dimension of $M$ explodes to hard to obtain your claim.

Comment: @HermannDöppes: Sure, see the edit.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Awesome, thank you very much.